# How to call ocr.space API with base 64

Tags: java, java-8, base64

I want call ocr.space(https://ocr.space/ocrapi) OCR API with base 64 using java.

I have used the following code , but getting error in output.

Code I have used...

```
try {
        URL obj = new URL("https://api.ocr.space/parse/image"); // OCR API Endpoints

        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("apikey", "******");

        con.setDoOutput(true);
        File file = new File("C:\\App_development\\OCRIMG.JPG");
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        InputStream finput = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] imageBytes = new byte[(int)file.length()];
        finput.read(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
        finput.close();
        String imageStr = Base64.encodeBase64String(imageBytes);
        wr.writeBytes(imageStr);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();


        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    }
    catch(Exception exx)
    {
        exx.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Exception  I am getting

```
Response Code : 200
{"OCRExitCode":0,"IsErroredOnProcessing":false,"ErrorMessage":["Parameter name '/9j/……..' is invalid. Valid parameters: apikey,url,language,isoverlayrequired,base64image,iscreatesearchablepdf,issearchablepdfhidetextlayer,filetype,addressparsing,scale,detectorientation,istable,ocrengine,detectcheckbox,checkboxtemplate","Please check if you need to URL encode the URL passed in request parameters."],"ProcessingTimeInMilliseconds":"4"}
```

Any help will be highly apricated ….

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can change

```
String imageStr = Base64.encodeBase64String(imageBytes);
```

to

```
 String imageStr ="&base64image="+ Base64.encodeBase64String(imageBytes)+":<JPG>";
```

but i meet

```
{"OCRExitCode":99,"IsErroredOnProcessing":true,"ErrorMessage":["Some internal processing error occurred. Please give us some time, we are looking into this!"],"ErrorDetails":"","ProcessingTimeInMilliseconds":"0"}
```

I don't know why .............

maybe you can reference this :
https://github.com/bsuhas/OCRTextRecognitionAndroidApp/blob/be7bb24a0e880cf174de9f16047fcb1b8c7447c6/app/src/main/java/com/ocrtextrecognitionapp/OCRAsyncTask.java